# Non-Mutually Exclusive Events and Using $P(A$ or $B) = P(A) + P(B) − P(A $ and $B)$.

Tags: probability

If we have the case where we role a six sided die, what is the probability that the number showing is either even or greater than 3.

I'm confused as to why you can't use the probability rule,

$P(A$ or $B) = P(A) + P(B) − P(A $ and $B)$.

If you use the rule you get,

$P(Even$ or $>3) = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{3}{6}−(\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{3}{6})$

$P(Even$ or $>3)$ = $\frac{3}{4}$

However, the book says the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: $P(\mbox{Even  and } > 3) = \frac{2}{6}$

Comment: I understand that, but why can't you use $(3/6)×(3/6)$?

Comment: For a single roll of a fair six-sided die, there is ***no*** event whose probability is $\frac34.$ (The only possible probabilities are $\frac06,\frac16,\frac26,\frac36,\frac46,\frac56,\frac66.$) The multiplication rule $P(A\cap B=P(A)P(B)$ is only valid when $A$ and $B$ are ***independent*** events.

Comment: So you mean to say that you can only use that rule if two separate events are occurring at the same time, bof?

Comment: No, I mean to say what I said. The rule $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ holds when $A$ and $B$ are ***INDEPENDENT EVENTS***. Actually, you can take that as the ***DEFINITION*** of "independent events".

Comment: $P(\mbox{Even} ) \cdot P( > 3 ) = \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{9}{36}$ but  $P(\mbox{Even and > 3} ) = \frac{2}{6}$.  But since $\frac{2}{6} \not = \frac{9}{36}$, the events are not independent.

Comment: For example, "the number showing is even" and "the number showing is $\gt2$ ***ARE*** independent events.

Comment: So, since we're only talking about a SINGLE role, you cannot have a probability that isn't $\frac{1}{6}, \frac{2}{6}...\frac{6}{6}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outcomes of a single roll of a die are $\require{enclose}\{1,\enclose{circle}{2},3,\enclose{box}{\enclose{circle}{4},5,\enclose{circle}{6}}\}$, where I have indicated the outcomes which are $\enclose{circle}{\lower{1ex}{}\textrm{even}\raise{2ex}{}}$ and $\enclose{box}{\textrm{greater than three}}$, let us call these events $A$ and $B$ respectively.   All six outcomes may occur without bias, so it is easy to see that $$\begin{align} \mathsf P(A) = 3/6,\\ \mathsf P(B)=3/6,\\ \mathsf P(A\cap B)=2/6,\\ \mathsf P(A\cup B)=4/6.\end{align}$$

Which testifies that : $\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$, as it should.

However, it is also clear that $\mathsf P(A\cap B)\neq \mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)$.   These events are *not* independent.

And we can likewise see that the conditional probability measures are:
$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(A\mid B) = 2/3,\\ \mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)=1/3,\\ \mathsf P(B\mid A)=2/3,\\ \mathsf P(B\mid A^\complement)=1/3.\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Graham Kemp. I was just wondering how you can tell that the event is $not$ independent, I'm having some trouble seeing it.

Comment: @tyrlR Only when $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)$ are the events independent, *otherwise* they are not (and vice versa).  Likewise only when $\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ are the events independent, *otherwise* they are not.  That's all it comes down to.